`Drop` for list of elements of different dimensions
MWE is the following list
{{{1,2,3},4},{{a,b,c},d}}

I want to Drop the 3 and c here. (In reality, it is a very long list of elements of this type and the 3 and c here could be anything.)
Unfortunately I don't know how to tell MMA the fact that I can go into lower layers for some of the elements.
e.g. Drop[list, None, None, None, {3}] will not work since it cannot tell that I don't want to go into the 4, but rather in the list {1,2,3}.
Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?
EDIT: For future readers: The goal was to drop the third element (regardless of its value/symbol) of the lowest layer possible. In this example it would be 3 and c, but it should be generally only dependent on their position, not value.

list[[All, 1, -1]] = Nothing?

I don't understand what you mean @ydd Executing your code gives me precisely what I want to drop though...

@ydd Now I put it together thanks to Asuka's answer. However as I stated under the answer, I cannot guarantee that c and 3 doesn't appear as duplicates somewhere else. Also Im concerned about performance.

I just set the last element of the first element of each pair (which would be 3 in the first pair, and c in the second pair) to Nothing, it doesn't depend on them being c and 3. It would probably be helpful to state what criterion you want to drop elements by.

@ydd just their position. It could have been {{{1,1,1},1},{{1,1,1},1}}, and I would still want to drop the last 1 of the lowest possible layer. Sjoerd Smit already gave a very clean answer though.

If I understand your structure correctly, this should be the most efficient way I can think of:
MapAt[Most, {{{1, 2, 3}, 4}, {{a, b, c}, d}}, {All, 1}]


list = {{{1, 2, 3}, 4}, {{a, b, c}, d}};

After clarification, We set the last element of each pair's first element to nothing:
list[[All, 1, -1]] = Nothing;
list

(*{{{1, 2}, 4}, {{a, b}, d}}*)

This works for longer lists as well:
list = ConstantArray[{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, 10];
list[[All, 1, -1]] = Nothing;
list
(*
{{{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 
  1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}}
*)


Oops, I did not understand your code then. If it also works on duplicate element lists, its a valid answer. I sadly cannot accept it after already accepting another answer. Sorry

@Confuse-ray30 You can always change the accepted answer.

@avpaderno No, the other answer works as well (and is just as good as far as I can see. I also learnt about MapAt through that answer, which was very helpful). But I wanted to say that his answer is nice too.

@Confuse-ray30 Then, it's not that you cannot accept another answer; it is that you already decided which answer to accept. I thought you did not know the accepted answer can always be changed.

{{{1,2,3},4},{{a,b,c},d}} /. {3 -> Nothing, c -> Nothing}


{{{1, 2}, 4}, {{a, b}, d}}


edit: so it's remove the position.
then another way:
{{1,2,3},4} /. {{x__, t_}, y__} :> {{x},y}


{{1, 2}, 4}

so Map it
Map[#/. {{x__, t_}, y__} :> {{x},y} &]  [ {{{1,2,3},4},{{a,b,c},d}} ]

but not fast.

Thanks for the answer. But since 3 and c can be literally anything, I don't know what to replace by nothing. I have to manually check e.g. via the code from ydd, and then thread ->Nothing to it. But is this a fast method? I cannot guarantee that 3 and c don't appear multiple times either.

Yes, it works now, thanks!

Another way is to use MapApply as follows:
{Most@#1, #2} & @@@ {{{1, 2, 3}, 4}, {{a, b, c}, d}}


{{{1, 2}, 4}, {{a, b}, d}}


Delete[{1, -1}] /@ lst

(* {{{1, 2}, 4}, {{a, b}, d}} *)


Using ReplaceAll and Span:
{{{1, 2, 3}, 4}, {{a, b, c}, d}} /. v_?VectorQ :> v[[;; -2]]

